# Orientation not working on iOS using Sencha Touch 2 and Cordova

Tags: ios, sencha-touch-2, cordova-2.0.0

I've written a simple app which does very little except navigate between pages, using the Sencha Touch 2 framework.
The app is now ported across to iOS using the Cordova templates.

However, for some reason orientation changes don't seem to be working.

I'm not looking to catch the event - just allow the default behaviour of rotating to fit the new view size.

Is there anything I should be looking for or any other information I need to provide?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: For some reason, when the app is deployed to iPhone - the orientation works as expected. It ONLY breaks when using an iPad.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it just stay in portrait/landscape mode? Or is there a visual issue? Are you sure orientation is enabled in your Xcode project?

Comment: It stays in the start up orientation, as though locked (the iPad definitely isn't locked). I have also enabled all four orientations through xCode by clicking on the four options.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate areas for the interface orientation, one for iPhone and one below it for the iPad. Make sure you've clicked all four options for the iPad.

Comment: I'm aware of that, they are both set up correctly. Originally it was an iPad only app, now it is Universal and I have locked the orientation for the iPhone (intentionally) but want to leave all orientation options available for the iPad.

Comment: Check your "Supported interface orientations" in your info.plist file

Comment: All four orientations are listed under the iPad section (as expected)